Tableau Filter multiple columns with 1 filter
The simple version of this is I have three columns that have scores 1-10. That is all three columns have a score from 1-10. I would like to make a single filter that checks all three columns for one or many values. So if I say filter on Scores of 2, it will show any row where column1, column2, column3 had a 2 in it despite what the other 2 columns have. This is of course very easy in SQL with an OR statement Where (Column1 = 2 OR Column2 = 2 or Column3 = 2)
I have tried to make a combined columned column, but that simply make a new column with all the combination, this might be the first step as I could possibly use a Like filter with this. However, my actual values are not as simple as 1-10 and columns 1,2,3 do not always have the same values so the parameters would need to get it's list generated from all 3 and me a multi value. For example. There are maybe 6000 possible values, but a given reports might have 50 different ones in each column so that the final list would have 150.
In the end it might be: List1(Value2),List2(Value16),List3(Value25) then if any of those 3 values exist in any of the 3 columns it would filter.

I am making progress, I am thinking it is something like a 2nd data source to generate a list of all values in Column 1,2,3 (done), populate a Parameter with those values (done), now I am trying to make that parameters multi select or select all, so I can create a calculated field to filter on, then create some IF( IN or logic) to filter based on.

Make a boolean record-level calculated field that indicates whether a record should be included or not, and then place that field on the filter shelf, keeping only records where it evaluates to True.
For example, create a parameter named Score_Of_Interest to allow the user to select a single score, and then your boolean field, named say Include_This_Record?, could be defined as:
[Field_One] = [Score_Of_Interest] OR [Field_Two] = [Score_Of_Interest] OR [Field_Three] = [Score_Of_Interest]
You can extend by adding a boolean parameter to overide the particular Score of Interest and give the user the option to include all records. Or by using a set instead of a parameter to allow the user to select multiple scores to include.
In essence, use parameters to ask the user single valued questions, and calculated fields to compare their responses with data records.

Thanks for the response. I am following, but the problem I have to get to this point is, getting the values into a single place. A parameters for example only allows 1 column as the source. I tried to join a separate data source with all possible values, but since Tableau only allows AND joins and not OR that is Column1 = Value AND Column2 = Value AND Column3 = Value the resulting data gives me only the values were all 3 columns are the same, not where they differ which is 99% of the case.

I do not count this as a true answer, but it did work so I will leave it behind. I created a 2nd data source with every possible value then Cartesian it on a column I knew every row had reliable values so I could join the two data sets on. Then I did the formula described above.

You should look into pivoting your data source. Tableau can do that easily and it sounds like a good fit for your problem - and more manageable than your other approach
